# Image Processing: Converting Image to Grayscale

Tags: python, image, grayscale

I am new to Python and am having trouble converting this image to grayscale after googling the formula. Did I apply it wrongly? My image is tinted green no matter what I try.

> 0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B

```
    import image

img= image.Image("luther.jpg")
win= image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
img.draw(win)
img.setDelay(1,100)

for row in range(img.getHeight()):
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        p=img.getPixel(col, row)
        newRed= 0.2989*p.getRed()
        newGreen= 0.5870*p.getGreen()
        newBlue= 0.1140*p.getBlue()
        newpixel= image.Pixel(newRed, newGreen, newBlue)
        img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)
        
img.draw(win)
win.exitonclick()enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting fact, most people use these weights originating from analog screens and no one takes into account that digital screens are already weighed... if not, then ffffff (max intensity for rgb) would not look white, therefore these weights are probably redundant. Anyway, add you noticed, for greyscale rgb all need the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have figured it out. I tried to solve this problem without any libraries and here is my simple solution:

```
import image

img= image.Image("luther.jpg")
win= image.ImageWin(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight())
img.draw(win)
img.setDelay(1,100)

for row in range(img.getHeight()):
    for col in range(img.getWidth()):
        p=img.getPixel(col, row)
        grayscale= (p.getRed()+ p.getGreen()+ p.getBlue())/3
        newRed= grayscale
        newGreen= grayscale
        newBlue= grayscale
        newpixel= image.Pixel(newRed, newGreen, newBlue)
        img.setPixel(col, row, newpixel)
        
img.draw(win)
win.exitonclick()
```